# Combining rows + Concatenating values for a large dataset (Converting SQL export to multivalued)

Tags: r

I have an SQL export of 5+ million records in CSV. I want to combine rows with the same PDP_ID field and concatenate their values from a column into a new column

I'm using the following functions, but they simply take way too long to execute and don't seem to progress:

```
PDP_ID <- unique(data$PDP_ID)

getDetailNumbers <- function(i)(paste(data$DETAIL_NUMBER[data$PDP_ID==i],collapse="@"))

DETAIL_NUMBERS <- aaply(PDP_ID,1,getDetailNumbers,.expand=FALSE,.progress="text")
```

After obtaining the (PDP_ID, DETAIL_NUMBERS) data.frame my plan was to merge this with the original dataframe.

PDP_ID contains about 4.1 million records. What would be the fastest way to handle this case? Splitting the file?
The 'data' dataframe is sorted on PDP_ID. I've also tried using the snowfall package to use both cpu cores, to no avail.

```
Sample data:

"PDP_ID","STREETNAME_DUTCH","ACTUAL_BOX_NUMBER","DETAIL_NUMBER"
111115,"An entry which wont be combined",
231313,"Street two",12
231313,"Street two",15
231313,"Street two",17
467626,"a third entry",1
467626,"a third entry",2
638676,"another which wont be combined",

Desired result:

"PDP_ID","STREETNAME_DUTCH","ACTUAL_BOX_NUMBER","DETAIL_NUMBER"
111115,"An entry which wont be combined",
231313,"Street two",12@15@17
467626,"a third entry",1@2
638676,"another which wont be combined",
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: Thanks, added sample data/desired result

Comment: I don't understand your data. You have 4 column names, but only 3 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is a bit strange as you have 4 column names and only 3 columns so I removed one column name.

Anyway, using `data.table` this should be very fast

First, you data

```
df <- read.csv(text = '"PDP_ID","STREETNAME_DUTCH","DETAIL_NUMBER"
111115,"An entry which wont be combined",
231313,"Street two",12
231313,"Street two",15
231313,"Street two",17
467626,"a third entry",1
467626,"a third entry",2
638676,"another which wont be combined",')
```

The solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , list(STREETNAME_DUTCH = STREETNAME_DUTCH[1],
                  DETAIL_NUMBER = paste(DETAIL_NUMBER, collapse = "@")), by = PDP_ID]
```

Result

```
#    PDP_ID                STREETNAME_DUTCH DETAIL_NUMBER
# 1: 111115 An entry which wont be combined            NA
# 2: 231313                      Street two      12@15@17
# 3: 467626                   a third entry           1@2
# 4: 638676  another which wont be combined            NA
```

---

Alternatively, you could try `dplyr` (also very fast)

**Imprtant note**: `dtach` the `plyr` package first, using `detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)`

The solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(PDP_ID) %>%
  summarise(STREETNAME_DUTCH = STREETNAME_DUTCH[1],
            DETAIL_NUMBER = paste(DETAIL_NUMBER, collapse = "@"))
```

Result

```
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# 
#   PDP_ID                STREETNAME_DUTCH DETAIL_NUMBER
# 1 111115 An entry which wont be combined            NA
# 2 231313                      Street two      12@15@17
# 3 467626                   a third entry           1@2
# 4 638676  another which wont be combined            NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the dplyr example works as expected and within reasonable time!

Comment: I let it run for about 20 minutes before trying the dplyr instead. However I did include about 10 extra columns (COL2 = COL2[1] etc...) in the setDT example (which I omitted from the sample data for simplicity) which I'm including in the dplyr now.